# Referencing JBoss vault from .properties file

Tags: java, jboss

Using JBoss EAP 7, I have a .properties file included in the classpath successfully.

I have also set up a vault, and inserted one value via the command line. I checked that the value exists.

I'm trying to use the vault entry in my application. So for example, in the properties file, if I put something like:

```
token.secret=mysecret
```

and then run one of my POST requests, it returns a key. I can run my `JUnit` test then and the assertion comes back true, that the encoding of the key did use the value "mysecret".

So if I put in "mysecret" into my vault:

```
vault.bat --keystore ..\vault\vault.keystore --keystore-password <password> --alias vault --vault-block mySecret --attribute myAtt --sec-attr mysecret --enc-dir ../vault --iteration 97 --salt abcdefgh
```

the command line gives back this to use:

```
${VAULT::mySecret::myAtt::1}
```

And then if I use this in my .properties file:

```
token.secret=${VAULT::mySecret::myAtt::1}
```

And make the same POST request, and run the JUnit test, it's saying the key returned wasn't generated from "mysecret".

How can I use the value in the vault within the properties file to get my `JUnit` test to pass?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an official answer of how I want it, but here is an alternative that can be used*.

Instead of referencing the vault from within the .properties file, you can put it within whichever standalone.xml (if of course you're using standalone mode) file your JBoss is using, under the system-properties node (create it if it's not there already):

```
<property name="token.secret" value="${VAULT::mySecret::myAtt::1}"/>
```

This then passes my assertion test.

*<sub>I'd still like someone to come along and tell me how to reference it from the .properties file...</sub>

Answer (score -1):

1. Setup vault and store the vault property in a property file for e.g.

   ```
   //vault.property file contents

   KEYSTORE_URL=/home/userid/jboss/jbossvault.jceks
   KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=MASK-0Kuitk9Sz/R./bViQcAEXY
   KEYSTORE_ALIAS=appln_name_vault
   SALT=12345678
   ITERATION_COUNT=888
   ENC_FILE_DIR=/home/userid/jboss
   ```
2. add in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

   a. vault section

   ```
   <vault>  
         <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="${KEYSTORE_URL}"/>  
         <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" value="${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}"/>  
         <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_ALIAS" value="${KEYSTORE_ALIAS}"/>  
         <vault-option name="SALT" value="${SALT}"/>  
         <vault-option name="ITERATION_COUNT" value="${ITERATION_COUNT}"/>  
         <vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="${ENC_FILE_DIR}"/>  
   </vault>
   ```

   b. ssl key store section

   ```
   <server-identities>
       <ssl>
           <keystore path="$JBOSS_HOME/keystore/Appln_Cert_KeyStore.jks" keystore-password="${VAULT::Appln_SSL_block::passphrase::1}"/>
       </ssl>
   </server-identities>
   ```
3. start jboss eap in standalone background mode
   nohup $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -P /home/userid/jboss/vault-config.properties &